# risc-v assembly code, c to assembly(bubble sort). when i use risc-v simulator-web, i get to this error. i i didn't solve it

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort, riscv

i try to translate c to assembly code - (risc-v)
but i met this screen and error when i use web risc-v simulator.
i use it

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2019sp/riscv/interpreter/
https://riscv.vercel.app/#

but simulators give error that don't read and unknown code to me.

so i think that i mistake for my code or i misused simulator

are you teaching me about my mistake?

this is my assembly code

```
.data
v:
.word 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5 # Array data

.text
.globl main
la a0, v

swap:
    slli t1, a1, 2
    add t1, a0, t1
    lw t0, 0(t1)
    lw t2, 4(t1)
    sw t2, 0(t1)
    sw t0, 4(t1)
    ret

sort:
    addi sp, sp, -20
    sw ra, 16(sp)
    sw s6, 12(sp)
    sw s5, 8(sp)
    sw s4, 4(sp)
    sw s3, 0(sp)

    mv s5, a0
    mv s6, a1
    li s3, 0

outer:
    bge s3, s6, outerExit
    addi s4, s3, -1

inner:
    blt s4, zero, innerExit
    slli t0, s4, 2
    add t0, s5, t0
    lw t1, 0(t0)
    lw t2, 8(t0)
    ble t1, t2, innerExit

    mv a0, s5
    mv a1, s4
    jal ra, swap

    addi s4, s4, -1
    j inner

innerExit:
    addi s3, s3, 1
    j outer

outerExit:
    lw s3, 0(sp)
    lw s4, 4(sp)
    lw s5, 8(sp)
    lw s6, 12(sp)
    lw ra, 16(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 20
    ret



main:
    
    # Calculate the number of elements in the array
    li a1, 6  # 6 elements in the array

    # Call the sort function
    jal ra, sort

    # Exit the program
    li a7, 10  # Exit system call
    ecall
```

when i write this code i used my lecture sources and chat gpt

correct my faults - if i use misknoledge
recommend risc-v web simulator
recommend risc-v tutorial site or pdf or etc

Comment: What errors?  A [mcve] needs to include details on what problems you're getting.  The point of Stack Overflow is to answer specific questions that might be useful to future readers (e.g. that have the exact same error message for the same reason), not general tutoring.  See also https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ / https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.  Showing your C algorithm would also be a good idea.

Comment: The online simulator you're using doesn't appear to have a real debugger, but it does show a trace of execution so you can at least see what was going on when something faulted.  (A debugger is an essential tool for learning asm, much more than most languages.)

Comment: ohh sorry, i attached error image, but board didn't save it

error is it
Latest execution time: 2023. 10. 17. 오후 6:46:59
Instruction Error: unknown opcode .data at line #1

Comment: Don't post pictures of text in the first place; copy/paste as text.  (https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ explains reasons why this is bad).  Anyway, see if it supports `.section .data` or `section .data`.  Neither of the examples built-in to the https://riscv.vercel.app/ site use a `.data` section.  The readme for it on https://github.com/9oelM/risc-v-web-simulator mentions there being a doc as part of Kite, but also that that online simulator was just made for fun.  So I wonder if it supports sections at all; it might not.  Simulators you can run locally like RARS do.

Comment: If you're taking a course, make sure you're using the same simulator your course expects, or one compatible with it.  Assembly language is very non-portable, e.g. different OSes have different system calls available, and different ways to invoke them, so one simulator might not run code that works in another, and they both might not run code that would run under Linux on a real system.

Comment: thank you
i will check this site reference with my code and i search other simulator. whenever i write other topic in stack overflow, i must check my image and rule